# Outlook Calendar Reccurence: Meeting every day except every other Monday

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, meetings

I have a case, when I have meeting every day, but even Mondays (like, July, 6th or July, 20th) we have a day off. I'd like to create a calendar meeting for this purposes, but looks like I cannot figure how to make it work.

I can create recurring calendar evens for everyday calendar and remove unrelated days, but this is not correct way how to do it. I'd like to see correct solution for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to setup 2 meetings. One weekly including all weekdays except Monday, and the other setting a weekly for every 2 weeks on Monday.